# MySQL Visual Studio 2015 You have a usable connection already

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015

I'm fairly experienced with Visual Studio 2013 and I'm now upgrading to VS 2015 and running into and issue adding a new datasource to a Windows Forms Application.  It is very easy to recreate my issue.

Here's my setup:

Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise 2015 Update 3
MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.6
Connector/Net 6.9.9

Note: The above configuration is supported according to the support information matrix located at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html and I've also tried just about every other permutation of supported software listed there.

Here's how to recreate the issue:

New C# Windows Forms Application
Add New Data Source
Database
  Dataset
  New Connection (connects just fine)
  Save the connection
Choose your database objects
  Select any table
  Finish

Error: Some updating commands could not be generated automatically. The database returned the following error:
You have a usable connection already.

Grateful for anyone who can even give a clue as to what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Install `mysql-for-visualstudio-2.0.4.msi` ([here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/2.0.html)).
2. Install `Connector/Net 6.9.9.msi` ([here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html)).

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works.  It seems that a prior bug in MySQL for Visual Studio is fixed in version 2.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I found.  As I delved further I found that something (I know not what) was expecting Connector/net 6.9.9 and something else (again I don't know what) was expecting Connector/net 6.9.8.  There is nothing in my projects or installation which should have referenced 6.9.8. In any event, I installed 6.9.8 and everything has worked perfectly since.

Comment: I can attest that uninstalling 6.9.9 and installing 6.9.8 worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for the last 24 hours.

First: have you deleted any project files from VS? I went to my recycle bin and restored everything from VS I had deleted.

This resolved the issue. Make sure any data connections from VS are restored.

If that doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Here's more detail:  I was moving to a new hard drive and at the same time upgrading to VS 2015 from VS 2013.   The new drive had a fresh install of Win 10 and VS 2015.  I installed MySQL for VS and Connector/Net then copied the project folder from the old VS 2013 to new VS 2015.  That's it.  Should be a pretty clean install.  Note that I first had data access issues with the existing projects but also had issues with completely new projects. I'm puzzled and think the only option for me is to return to my old drive.

Comment: Which version of MYSQL?

Comment: '5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2'

Answer (score 0):

I tried out almost all the above mentioned solutions all of them failed at last what i did is

1. Created DataSet manually by right clicking the project and added a new dataset.
2. Then created DataTable in that with all the columns as same in the query.
3. You can see **Report Data** Menu in rdlc report. Under that you can see DataSet you can drag and put datatable column to rdlc report.
4. In backend you can write something like this

   ```
           var ds = this.GetData();
           var dt = ds.Tables[0];
           ReportViewer1.Reset();
           ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Report1.rdlc");
           ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dt)); // same name as dataset created under report data menu

           ReportViewer1.DataBind();

           ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Uninstall MySQL Connector/NET
2. Reinstall MySQL Connector/NET