# Visual studio c# application connect to MySql server

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio 2017 but i made a simple Windows Form application that needs to connect with my existing Mysql Database.

I can make a connection and see some tables but after selecting them I get this error: [image: error]

I did a full install of MySQL for windows including Connector and MySQL for visual studio latest versions because that was the answer for other people who had this problem but after install and reboot nothing has changed.

I also added the Mysql.data reference.

I don't get what causes this unexpected error. I tried with 2 different databases but the same result.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41351527/1033684

Comment: "I did a full install of mysql for windows including Connector and mysql for visual studio latest versions"

Comment: i tried multiple versions but nothing worked so i did a complete install with all possible mysql components. Including those you linked

Comment: maybe you've installed the wrong version, such as a 32 bit.  I've made that mistake before.

Comment: have this error now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8sve.png

Comment: I'd go through all the answers in the link I have already posted. It looks the same issue.

Comment: it is but i can't do that. i installed the 6.9.8 as recomended but i can't installed the 2.0.4 because thats outdated and not for 2017 visual studio