# You have a usable connection already

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I downloaded and installed visual studio 2017 community edition and i installed mysql community 8.0.15. In visual studio 2017 data connections work fine for mysql i can store data through visual studio. But when i create data source after selecting the table it shows some updating commands could not be generated automatically database returned following error : you have a usable connection. Then it shows another error could not retrieve schema from table . I had tried other steps by downgrading connector and mysql for visual studio but it does not work.

This is the first error:

[image]

This is the second error after clicking ok:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41351527/5346438 this was not helpful?

Comment: It shows "Unable to retrieve the list of databases. Authentication method 'caching_sha2_password not supported by any of the available plugins'"

Comment: For visual studio 2017 which will be the correct version of mysql???

Comment: version 8.0.x. Which entity framework are you using?

Comment: I just downloaded 1.2.7 and 6.9.8 cleared my error thanks for the help. But it shows an error failed to add relations specified cast is not valid. But data source is created fine.

Comment: I just downloaded mysql for visual studio 1.2.7 and connector/net 6.9.8 and it cleared the error. But why is the connector/net 8.0.x not supporting visual studio 2017???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me too. To confirm, with Visual Studio 2017 vb.net I finally got it to connect to a remote MySql database without errors using the slightly newer MYSQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8 and that same older connector vs 6.9.8. (I also had it working well with the free dotConnect for MySQL 8.12 Express). Tables load successfully into a Datagridview, zero issues. Well one proviso. I can only add one table on adding a datasource to a Datagridview. However you can add more tables in Design View later on.
Hope that helps someone else.