# MySql Visual Studio 2017 (Error: You have a usable connection already)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and these are the errors I encountered when I drag my table to the `dataset`:

> Some updating commands could not be generated automatically. The database returned the following error:
>
> You have a usable connection already.

[image]

> Mouse drag operation failed.
>
> Could not retrieve schema information for table or view `access_rights`..

[image]

This is my setup currently installed:

- MySQL Connector C++ 8.0
- MySQL Connector J
- MySQL Connector Net 8.0.15
- MySQL Connector/ODBC 8.0
- MySQL Documents 8.0
- MySQL Examples and Samples 8.0
- MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8
- MySQL Installer - Community
- MySQL Router 8.0
- MySQL Server 8.0
- MySQL Shell 8.0.15
- MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

I already tried this:

- Visual Studio 2017 (Community, Professional, and Enterprise):

  MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8 or 2.0.5 with Connector/NET 6.9.8

Comment: Duplicates,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001594/you-have-a-usable-connection-already-error-in-visual-studio-2015-adding-data-s
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862525/mysql-visual-studio-2015-you-have-a-usable-connection-already?rq=1

Comment: mine is visual studio 2017

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in those threads.

Comment: yup and i also tried different version of mysql connector/net and mysql for VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve this i saw a random answer from another website

***Important***

***Uninstall both Mysql for VS and Connector/net
and you must first install Mysql for VS before connector/net***

and it works properly now

Answer (score 1):

Job Fine for me in Visual Studio 2019:

Uninstall MySQL Connector Net and MySQL for Visual Studio

Installed MySQL Connector Net 8.0.19 (Install this first)

Installed MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9 (Install last)

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for hours. I used the advice in another 2015 VS post.

Uninstalled MySQL Connector Net and MySQL for Visual Studio

Installed MySQL Connector Net 6.9.8

Installed MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7

And it worked after that.
I think it is important to install the connector before the visual studio. The latest version are not friendly and you need to downgrade.